# "Stars and bars" technique with integer numbers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm failing to extend the "stars and bars" technique from Natural to integer numbers. HELP!

> How many vectors $\mathbf{X}$ exist such that
>   $\mathbf{X}$ is a vector of $D$ integer numbers where
>   each element $\mathbf{X}(i)$ is between $-N$ and $+N$
>   and $\sum_{i=1}^D |\mathbf{X}(i)| = N$?

I'm looking for the combinatorial formula as a function of $D$ and $N$.

Thank you!

Comment: @amWhy and others - please help me improve the question! Would the following work: My context is numerical optimisation. 
I have a non-convex function f(X), with X being a vector of D dimensions. 
I am looking for the X that maximises f(X), with X(i) in the interval [-N,+N] and ∑|X(i)|=N. 
Because the function is non-convex, to find its maximum I will have to calculate f(X) for every X.
Calculating f(X) is expensive and depending on D (number of dimensions) N (points per dimension) and there can be many different X.
I want to estimate how the computational cost varies with D and N.

Answer (score 1):

The number of such vectors, i. e. the number of points of $1$-norm $N\geq 1$ in cubic lattice $\mathbb{Z}^D$  is equal to
$$A(D,N)=\sum_{k=1}^D\binom{D}{k}\binom{N-1}{k-1}2^k$$
where $1\leq k\leq D$ is the number of components which are different from zero,
$\binom{D}{k}$ is the number of ways to select $k$ component out of $D$, 
$2^k$ is the number of ways to arrange the sign of each non-zero component, and
$\binom{N-1}{k-1}$ is the number of positive integer solutions of the equation $z_1+\dots +z_k=N$ (see ["stars and bars"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_one) technique).
 See also [OEIS sequence A035607](http://oeis.org/A035607).

Comment: thanks! I've just simulated it in software and it works perfectly! I'll go head down and study the reasoning 

Comment: @Vito Well done. Let me know if you have any further doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Start by ignoring all the negative options for the $X(i)$.  Now you have a classic stars and bars problem that allows $0$ in the sum.  Any sum that involves $k$ zeros and $D-k$ nonzeros represents $2^{D-k}$ solutions because you can negate all the nonzero items.  You need to condition on the number of zeros.

Comment: thanks for the intuition!